# Python error NoneType

Tags: python

I have a Python script that uses BS4 to grab the html of a webpage. Then I locate a specific header field in the html to extract the text. I do this with the following:

```
r = br.open("http://example.com")
html = r.read()
r.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
# Get the contents of the html tag (h1) that displays results
searchResult = soup.find("h1").contents[0]
# Get only the number, remove all text
if not(searchResult == None):
    searchResultNum = int(re.match(r'\d+', searchResult).group())
else:
    searchResultNum = 696969
```

The actual HTML code doesn't change. It always looks like this:

```
<div id="resultsCount">
    <h1 class="f12">606 Results matched</h1>
</div>
```

The problem is, my script runs fine for maybe 4 minutes (varies) and crashes with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Me\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\PythonScripts\PythonScripts\setupscript.py", line 109, in <module>
    searchResultNum = int(re.match(r'\d+', searchResult).group())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I thought I was handling this error. I guess I just do not understand it. Can you help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `searchResult` does not start with a number `re.match(r'\d+', searchResult)` will be `None` and `None` does not have a group attribute.  Also `if not(searchResult == None):` is kinda bad, use `if searchResult:`

```
searchResultNum = 696969
if searchResult:
    m = re.match(r'\d+', searchResult)
    if m:
        searchResultNum = int(m.group())
```

Comment: ...the consequence being that he probably should be using `re.search()` instead of `re.match()`...

Comment: unless he only wants numbers at the beginning, his example text `606 Results matched` kind of implies that he does.